# need help in ADF trigger with Blob

Tags: triggers, azure-data-factory

which needs to be triggered when a file received in a Blob.
But the complex part is that there are 2 files, A.JSON and B.JSON which will be generated in 2 different locations.

So When A.JSON generated in location 1, the Pipeline A should trigger and also when B.JSON generated in Loation 2, the Pipeline A should trigger. I have done the blob trigger using 1 file on 1 location but not sure how to do when 2 different files come in 2 different locations .

[image]

Comment: I would use Logic Apps for the Blob triggers, one for each file/location. Each Logic App can execute the pipeline independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways you could do this.

1. Using ADF directly with conditions to evaluate if the file triggered is from a specific path as per your need.
2. Setup Logic Apps for each different paths you would want to monitor for blobs created.
3. Add two different triggers configured for different paths (best option)

> **First method:** *(This has an overhead of running every time a file is triggered in container.)*

**Edit the trigger to look through whole storage or all containers. Select the file type: JSON in your case.**

[image]

**Parameterize source dataset for dynamic container and file name**

[image]

**Create parameters in pipeline, one each for refering the folder path you want to monitor and one for holding the triggered filename.**

[image]

**where `receive_trigger_files` will be assigned the triggered file name dynamically.**

[image]

**I am showing an example here where a lookup activity would evaluate the path and execute the respective activities forward if triggered file path and our monitoring paths match.**

[image]

**another for the `path2`**

[image]

**For example a Get MetaData activity or any in your scenario**

[image]

**Lets manually debug and check for a file `exercise01.json` that is sored in `path2`**

[image]

You can also use IF condition activity similarly, but would require multiple steps or monitoring using activity statuses won't be clear.

[image]

> **Second method:** Setup a blob triggered logic app

[image]

**Run ADF pipeline using `Create a pipeline run` action, and set or pass appropriate parameters as explained previously.**

[image]

> **Third method:** Add 2 triggers each for a path you wish to monitor blob creation.

[image]